# Query to find DISTINCT between array of objects in Cosmos DB [ SQL API ]

Tags: distinct, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Azure Cosmos DB with SQL API and we need to find the DISTINCT values between array of objects in the same document. 
I have structured the collection in the following ways

1. I have 2 main attribute RID and RNAME. In the first collection, I have only one document which contains all the RID and RNAME mapping in the array of objects.

"Details":[
          {
           "RID":"1",
           "RNAME:"Car"
          },
          {
           "RID":"1",
           "RNAME:"Car"
          }]

2. In second collection, I have multiple documents for each RID and RNAME mapping.

   {
          "RID":"1",
          "RNAME:"Car"
   }

I am using Stored procedure and I need to know which one is a good way to get DISTINCT of RNAME using stored procedure.

Using first collection, I am not sure how to query to find DISTINCT RNAME between objects in the array.
Using second collection. when I use the SQL editor, the distinct Query works but not sure how to put it in Stored procedure.

DISTINCT Values of RNAME

Comment: The final destination is fetching the distinct values of RNAME,am i right? Why you used SP in this process? Does the query :` select distinct c.RNAME from c` meets your requirement,doesn't it?

Comment: Hi Jay, Yes the distinct command works when there is multiple documents but does not work if all content in a single document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.multiple documents

use sql:

```
select distinct c.RNAME from c
```

> 2.single document

use sql:

```
SELECT distinct d.RNAME FROM c
join d in c.Details
```

[image]